# AsQueryable().ToList() not returning any result in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I have implemented an `OData` web service. In the URL I am passing on `OData` queries and in my controller I have used

`var obj1 = [DbContext Class Object].[DbSet].AsQueryable();`

I want to convert `obj1` to `List()` and do some data manipulation on it.So I used

`var obj1 = [DbContext Class Object].[DbSet].AsQueryable().ToList();`

But I am not getting any response, I debugged the code, but it went in for long time from this line. I have searched a lot for the solution but no luck. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I implemented this on a small table with 2 rows, and I got the response in few seconds, but when I implemented on a larger table I returns nothing. I tried ToListAsync(), which returned NULL.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ? i.e. to get the data from AsQueryable() and operate on that ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to convert it to a Queryable .. DbSet<T> already implements IQueryable<T> so you have whatever methods you need anyway.